# Keras: How to get class label from model.predict when using sigmoid for binary classsification

Tags: numpy, keras

I have implemented a basic neural network in `keras` with `sigmoid` activation at the output layer. However, when I use `model.predict(x_new)` on my unseen data, it returns me a `numpy` array with values ranging `0-1`. I want a binary class output. How to do that?

Comment: You can use `predict_classes()` method. Alternatively, you can set a threshold of 0.5 to find samples belonging to class one: `class_one = preds > 0.5`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using Keras API and not Sequential Model. So can't use predict_classes method.

Comment: Therefore the only solution is to threshold probabilities manually.